# Problem adding spellcheck dictionary to firefox

Tags: firefox, dictionary

I've tried to install Finnish dictionary to the Firefox several times by right clicking text area and choosing Languages -> Add Dictionaries.

However, every time I restart Firefox, Finnish is not listed as installed language. How can I fix this? Ubuntu 12.10, Firefox 19.0.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not related to Ubuntu, but to Firefox and you should ask this in [Firefox support](https://support.mozilla.org/).

Anyway, I tried the same and saw that unfortunately there’s no Finnish spell-check dictionary between [Dictionaries & Language Packs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/) available for Firefox and you may install the language pack. The language pack is to translate Firefox interface into local languages and don’t include spell-check dictionaries.